# Check if user is banned or not

Tags: java, discord-jda

I cant seem to figure out how to check if a user is already banned if tried this `event.getGuild().retrieveBan(event.getUser()`
but you cant use an if statement with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the failure and success callbacks:

```java
guild.retrieveBan(user).queue(
  (success) -> {
    // the user is banned
  }, 
  (failure) -> {
    // the user is not banned
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

.retrieveBan() is an RestAction, which means that you need a .complete() after .retrieveBan()

Here is my Code:

```
   try {
        System.out.println(guild.retrieveBan(user).complete()); // is banned
    }catch (ErrorResponseException e) {
        // is NOT banned
    }
```